# какой вариант проверки переменной выбрать, если неизвестно содержит ли переменная какое-либо значение и была ли создана переменная

Tags: php

```
// получение данных посредством GET (может быть получение из БД):
if (isset ($_GET['data']) && preg_match('/^[0-9A-Z]{10}$/D', $_GET['data']))
    $query[] = 'data = "' . $_GET['data'] . '"'; // array

// варианты проверок:

// 1 вариант
if (isset ($query))
{
    // если параметр $_GET['data'] был передан, выполняем код
}
// 2 вариант
if (! empty ($query))
{
    // если параметр $_GET['data'] был передан, выполняем код
}
// 3 вариант
$query = null;

// здесь проверка if (isset ($_GET['data']) && preg_match...

if ($query)
{
    // если параметр $_GET['data'] был передан, выполняем код
}
```

Работают все 3 варианта.
Насколько мне известно, правильным будет 3 вариант - вначале следует объявить переменную, потом перезаписать, если были переданы параметры, и потом проверять содержится ли в ней что-то, чтобы поместить данные в БД.

Какой вариант выбрать и почему? (скорость проверки!)

Comment: Вы уверены, что это самое узкое место в вашем приложении?

Comment: Код какой-то странный, как в старом скетче, "тут играть, тут не играть, тут селедку заворачивали". Можете объяснить, ЗАЧЕМ ПИСАТЬ СЛОВАМИ "вот тут у меня такой-то код" вместо собственно кода? Лично я не поручусь что понимаю, что имеется в виду под каждым из вариантов

Comment: Можно ещё в первый `if` добавить `else`, который бы назначал значение `$query` по умолчанию. И вы всегда будете знать, что переменная есть :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лично я использую проверку с помощью `empty()`, так как этот метод проверяет и на существование переменной и на нулевое значение, пустой массив, пустую строку, false.

Детальное описание способов проверок можете найти по ссылке.
http://php.net/manual/ru/types.comparisons.php